# Why Travis CI can't connect to GitHub API?

Tags: continuous-integration, composer-php, travis-ci, http-status-code-403, github-api

I'm running the following commands in Travis CI for my [build](https://travis-ci.org/kenorb/drupal-sandbox/builds/82121457):

```
before_install:
  - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

script:
  - sudo composer -nqq update
```

I'm installing composer manually as I want to use `sudo` with it, as it's installed only for the user.

The error which I'm having are:

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (0.1)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download jakub-onderka/php-console-color from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/JakubOnderka/PHP-Console-Color/zipball/e0b393dacf7703fc36a4efc3df1435485197e6c1" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden)
    Now trying to download from source

  - Installing symfony/yaml (v2.7.4)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download symfony/yaml from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/Yaml/zipball/2dc7b06c065df96cc686c66da2705e5e18aef661" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden)
    Now trying to download from source
```

I've tried these links and they work fine.

Does it mean Travis is blocking GitHub API for some reason? If not, how do I fix it?

By fix, I mean either to know what's going on, or suppress these error messages (e.g. by using some special parameter in `composer` or changes to JSON file to force downloads from the source).

My `composer.json` file is:

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "/var/lib/vendor",
        "bin-dir": "/usr/local/bin"
    },
    "require": {
        "drush/drush": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

---

For the reference, the full `.travis.yml` looks like:

```
before_install:
  - env
  - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
  - sudo apt-get -qy update
install:
  - sudo apt-get install vagrant
script:
  - set -e # This makes build to fail on first error.
  - sudo composer -nqq update
  - make
  - make vm
after_failure:
 - sudo apt-get -qy install tree && - tree -d -L 6 # Print directory structure in the form of a tree.
 - env
sudo: true
language: php
python:
  - "5.5"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions are:

Remove:

- `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer`
- `sudo composer -nqq update`

First line: not needed, because Composer is pre-installed, when you use `language: php`.

Second line: its better to execute `composer install`, because `update` uses the data from `composer.lock` if your repo contains one. And sudo is not needed here.

(Sidenote on the  usage of `sudo` on Travis-CI:
sudo is only available in the non-containainer based infrastructure. I don't know if you really need this, but maybe you could switch to the faster container based infrastrucutre by setting `sudo: false` in your `travis.yml`, see http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/ . Just a hint.)

---

Add to `travis.yml`

```
before_install:
  - composer self-update
  - composer install --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader
```

First line: update the (possibly) outdated composer of this Travis instance.

Second line:  install dependencies described in `composer.json` with Composer.

---

The additional parameters to switch between downloading "Dist" or downloading "Source" are `--prefer-dist` and `--prefer-source`.

So its either

- `- composer install --prefer-dist --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader`

or

- `- composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader`

---

> Does it mean Travis is blocking GitHub API for some reason?

If its not a temporary issue, then its seems your Composer is running into the Github API rate-limit. The GitHub API allows only a low number of requests for unauthenticated users. You can raise the API limit by authenticating at Github from Travis.

See FAQ: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#api-rate-limit-and-oauth-tokens

Please try it with `prefer-source` first.

Answer (score 2):

Most probable reason for the error is limited amount of downloads from github. What you need to do is [create a token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) in your github account and add it globally to your composer with

`composer config -g github-oauth.github.com <your-token>`

Source: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#api-rate-limit-and-oauth-tokens